# How to style an image created using javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Thanks to Stack Overflow I managed to solve an issue I was having with inconsistent transitions by preloading an image using javaScript.

---

To skip over what is working I won't post all the code. In short, I have an image on my HTML and a button that when clicked triggers a transition in which another image takes its place with a slide down. The inconsistencies I was getting got solved by creating the img in my javascript (as it gets loaded faster that way). I then apply some classes that perform the transition. Here is the relevant code:

HTML

```
<div class="page page-1"><img src="myFirstImage.jpg" width="100%"></div>
<div id="myDiv"class="page page-2"></div>
```

CSS

```
.page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;

}

.page img {
   min-height: 100%;
}

 .pt-page-moveFromTop {
        -webkit-animation: moveFromTop 2s ease both;
        animation: moveFromTop 2s ease both;
    }

.pt-page-moveToBottom {
    -webkit-animation: moveToBottom 2s ease both;
    animation: moveToBottom 2s ease both;
}


@keyframes moveFromTop {
    from { -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); transform: translateY(-100%); }
}

@keyframes moveToBottom {
    from { }
    to { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); transform: translateY(100%); }
}
```

javaScript

```
var image2 = new Image(); 

image2.src = "mySecondImg.jpg";

$(document).ready( function () {

   $('.myButton').click(function(){

       $('.page-1').addClass('pt-page-moveToBottom');
       $('.page-2').append(image2);
       $('.page-2').addClass('pt-page-moveFromTop');

    });  
});
```

It all works, but my second image doesn't get styled with the classes "page" and "page-2". So my question is, how can I apply those styles to the image() I created in js. I've tried something like

```
image2.addClass("page page-2");
```

But that doesn't do it. What is the best way to accomplish this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: In css file .page.page-2 img {...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are mixing javascript and jquery here. The add class function will only work with a jquery element.

You should be doing someting like `$(image2).addClass("page page-2");`

Answer (score 1):

Since you used

```
var image2 = new Image(); 
image2.src = "mySecondImg.jpg";
```

then I guess you may want to use a pure JS solution until the end. Then, you can assign the image class using:

```
image2.className = "className";
```

or add another class name like this:

```
image2.className += " className"; //with a space before
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.page-2').addClass('pt-page-moveFromTop');` adds class to img **container**, not to `img` itself. You should do `$('.page-2 img').addClass('pt-page-moveFromTop');` instead.